# Solving a fifth order polynomial with changing values of coefficients

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, dynamic, polynomials

I have a fifth order polynomial in x whose coefficients depend on a certain variable k. Now, I want to find the real roots of that polynomial for each value of k, say from 0.1 to 2 in steps of 0.05 and after finding the roots, I need to plot the corresponding root versus the k from which it was obtained. How can I do that? If anyone could help, that would be highly appreciable.

Comment: "plot the corresponding root versus the k from which it was obtained": wouldn't there be up to five roots for each value of $k$, since the polynomial is fifth degree in $x$?

Comment: yes there would be five roots, but it turns out that only one of them is real and as I am only interested in the real root, so I get only one root for one k value. Actually I have done the problem taking each value of k and then solved it for each k. But that is time consuming and cumbersome. Moreover that method has one big disadvantage. If the value of one of the coefficients is changed, then I have to do the whole thing again.

Comment: It may be as simple as `Solve[yourPoly ==0, x, Reals]`, but you should really share your actual polynomial for further help.

Comment: The polynomial is of the form $$C_5x^5 + C_4x^4 + C_3x^3 + C_2x^2 + C_1x + C_0 = 0$$ where

Comment: \begin{align*} 
     C_5 &= \left. 1 + \frac{1}{k^2 \lambda^2} \right.\\ 
     C_4 &= \left. -3ku_{i0} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k^2 \lambda^2}\right) \right.\\ 
     C_3 &=\left.3 k^2 u^2_{i0} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k^2 \lambda^2}\right) - \omega^2_{pd}\right.\\
     C_2 &=\left. - \left( \omega^2_{pi} \nu_{in} + k^3 u^3_{i0}\left(1 + \frac{1}{k^2 \lambda^2}\right)\right)\right.\\
     C_1 &= \left. -3\omega^2_{pd} k^2 u^2_{i0}\right.\\ 
     C_0 &= \left. \omega^2_{pd} k^3 u^3_{i0}\right.\\ 
     \end{align*}

Comment: Apart from $k$, everything may be treated as constants, but situations may arise where we need to change the other parameters as well.

Comment: OK, now go back and add that information in the original question *as MMA code* so we can copy and paste it directly, rather than having to copy it by hand. Do not use subscripts or formatting. For instance, $\omega_{pd}^2$ should probably be simply `omegaPD^2` in your code. Pretty formatting is cumbersome to work with and it can get in the way of getting the problem solved.

Comment: What did you mean by MMA code? I didn't get it.

Comment: I mean as Mathematica code.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be along the lines of what you seek?

```
yourPoly = (x - 1) (x - 3) (x - k) (x - 2 k) (x - 6) + k;
solutions = x /. Solve[yourPoly == 0, x];
Plot[solutions, {k, 0.1, 2}]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: But in this case, as I have understood, while calculating the roots, you have taken $k$ to be constant then after getting the root, you have varied $k$. Am I right?

Comment: @SAGARMODAK Yes, since $k$ is technically a constant throughout in this context, i.e. ultimately it will have a numerical value.